# Convert this regex to be friendly within sed

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression, perl, xmlstarlet

I am trying to perform this regex with sed, but seems like sed does not support? It says invalid character range

```
echo "$info" | sed -e 's/(?:\d[\s-.]*){12,19}/*/g'
```

Trying to match any digits range with 12 to 19 regardless of whitespaces,-, or . characters

```
sed: 1: "s/(?:\d[\s-.]*){12,19}/ ...": RE error: invalid character range
```

Seems like the issue is fixed when I moved the dash up in the character range to `(?:\d[-\s.]*){12,19}` but it does nothing afterwards... Does that mean this is not matching? But regexr test cases say otherwise

Example:

```
A0000000000000000D
1234 1234 1234 1234
VISA 1234123412341234 EXP 1222 CVV 123
```

Comment: followup question at [Perl replacement with strings contain wildcard causes wrong output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654682/perl-replacement-with-strings-contain-wildcard-causes-wrong-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the regexp is the source of the error: `[\s-.]`

If you want `-` to be treated as just another character in a bracket expression, then put it at the **beginning** or the **end** of the expression.   Otherwise, it will be treated as a range.

For example:

- `[a-z]` means "match all lowercase letters from a to z"
- `[-az]` or `[az-]` mean "match a dash, an 'a', or a 'z'"

---

BTW, no version of sed that I know of understands the perl-ish `\d` as a synonym for `[0-9]` or `[:digit:]`.    Some versions of `sed` (e.g. GNU sed) understand `\s` as a synonym for spaces and tabs (`[:blank:]`), but certainly not all. And those that **do** understand `\s`, probably only understand it **outside** of bracket expressions (i don't know of any that do understand it inside `[]` but that doesn't mean there isn't some obscure sed variant that does).

And, AFAIK, sed doesn't understand perl's `(?:)` to mean a non-capturing subexpression.

To use Extended Regular Expression (ERE) features like {} without escaping them as `\{` and `\}`, you need to use sed's `-E` option (and escaping them might be a GNU extension, like it is for `\+`, so may not work for all versions of sed).

To match 12-19 digits that **might** contain spaces or dashes and replace them with asterisks, you first need to remove the spaces and dashes, and then try to match 12-19 digits.  e.g.

```
echo "$info" | sed -E -e 's/[[:blank:]-]//; s/[[:digit:]]{12,19}/*/g'
```

NOTE: If you don't care about portability and are never likely to deal with ancient or proprietary versions of sed, this will be fine.  Otherwise, stick to Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) or use `perl -n` or `perl -p` instead of `sed` (and definitely use perl if you want to use perl's dialect of regular expressions).

Also note that this will affect the entirety of whatever is in `$info`, so all spaces and dashes will be stripped.  Depending on what's in $info, this may not be what you want.

If $info is likely to contain other text (e.g. `VISA 1234123412341234 EXP 1222 CVV 123` instead of just `1234123412341234`) then you should probably use awk or perl instead of sed so that you can easily work with each individual field rather than the entire line.

Comment: Sorry I have updated the context, I figured out this issue.

Comment: `{}` still doesn't work without -E

Comment: So I have to use `perl` at the end of the day huh? I've looked briefly to see if I can use perl on a variable, does not seem like that is an option. Thank you for the additional info as well, I was suspecting the first 3 points as I was trying to fix this.

Comment: What do you mean by "use perl on a variable"?    If you mean "Can I echo a variable into a perl script like I can with a sed script?" then yes, you can: e.g. `echo "$info" | perl -p -e '.....'`.     You will probably find, though, that unless what you're doing is trivial, you will almost certainly be better off writing the entire script in perl rather than a shell script that calls awk, sed, and/or perl multiple times.

Comment: I see, I can just ignore the filename param. And I would love to write in perl at this point but I am not amazing with perl and this is just one small task out of the bigger function of the script I already written in bash. Thank you though!

Comment: `\{...\}` are standard and were added to BREs before `{..}` were  added to EREs (some EREs like in some awk / egrep implementations still don't support `{...}` as adding them breaks backward compatibility),

Comment: While GNU or ast-open `sed` supports `\s` outside of bracket expression, it doesn't support it inside.

Comment: Note that  ast-open `sed` does support `(?:...)`  with `-A` or `-X` (for ast-open *augmented regexps*). ssed supports PCRE with `-R`.

Comment: `\s` is more of an equivalent of `[[:space:]]`, not `[[:blank:]]`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas not acccording to `info sed` which specifically says "spaces or tabs".   Also, re BRE vs ERE vs standard vs GNU/BSD/whatever extensions for sed - i gave up keeping track of that years ago.  There are so many variants that it's just not worth the bother.   I stick to GNU or FreeBSD sed. or just use perl because there's far greater consistency in REs between different version numbers of perl than there is between different implementations of sed.

Comment: @BaoThai the best way to get good with perl (or any language. or anything at all) is to practice it. starting with simple things and working your way up to more advanced stuff is **exactly** the right way to learn.

Comment: I just read `info sed` again and it also says "Newlines embedded in the pattern/hold spaces will also match".   so `\s` in GNU sed is somewhere between `[:blank:]` and `[:space:]`.

Comment: See `printf '\r\u2002\f\v\n' | sed 's/\s/x/g'`. `\s` comes from perl where it  is whitespace (`[ \f\n\r\t\v]`, `\v` recently added in default ASCII mode)

Comment: yeah, i know where \s came from.   it used to mildly annoy me that other REs didn't have the perl niceties.  eventually I stopped caring about it.  some of them have since borrowed some features from perl and while that vaguely pleases me, i still don't care very much.

Comment: Note that POSIX requires `[\s]` to match on either backslash or `s`. However it does also require `[\t]` to match on either backslash or `t`, but in GNU `sed`, that matches on a tab instead (unless POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment), so it's not impossible future versions of GNU `sed` will understand `\s` there as well.

Comment: This is kind of random but why does adding a space in my replace string with wildcard causes all the files on my system to basically perform an `ls`... `perl -p -e 's/(?:\d[-\s.,]*){12,16}/* /g'`

Comment: @BaoThai i don't know what you mean by that, but if something weird is happening, i'd guess: a) you're doing something weird with quoting, and b) the perl command you're showing isn't the one you executed.

Comment: I am trying to post a new question but it's not letting me for some buggy reason, can I add it in edit instead?